# TButtons and "runtime themes": peculiar behavior

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, form-designer

Have you seen this?

I have a little utility application (for easy load / test xml generation from CDS and/or DBGo), and I had put some buttons (the poorest button of all, TButton) to trigger some actions.

I never paid attention to appearance, because I'm the only one that uses it. So today I added a new button, and they appeared different from the others in designer - but not when running. It's just an copy and paste process (change the button name, caption and event - the rest is equal to the origin).

When I looked the other buttons have an grey gradient and round corners, the button I copied and pasted not (just a bare rectangle). When running all buttons where just bare rectangles.

So I discovered that on designer, W7 and delphi are applying themes. On running, they are obeying the `Project/Options/Application/Enable runtime themes` flag.

This is annoying. There's a way to make Delphi doing that obeying the project options flag on forms designer?
(Or even manually if is not possible to automate that)?

EDIT:
[image: The form in question]

The toolbars on the form are from CNWizards ;-)

EDIT II:

Apart of disabling themes for the IDE executable, all buttons get themed equally if the form (or project) is reloaded. **But it's really weird**.

Comment: `TButton` is the best button control there is on the Microsoft Windows platform, for it is native.

Comment: So you are seeing both themed and classic buttons on the design surface. How about a screenshot.

Comment: I didn't knew that SO have an upload image dialog... Most foruns requite you to host the image somewhere on the new to be able to link.... Nice...

Comment: Is the 'classic-looking' button really TButton? Is it by any chance a TButton's (custom) descendant?

Comment: @Andriy M: no, all are TButtons. **100% sure**

Comment: Andreas' answer is the chosen one. But Hasan S remembering of old behaviors is informative - there were friend that had the inverse problem with the classic Delphis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enable/disable themes in the IDE, then open the properties of `bds.exe`, select the 'Compatibility' tab, and make sure that the 'Disable visual themes' checkbox is unchecked/checked.

Programs that you run from the IDE will inherit the compatibility settings of the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Delphi IDE itself is an application and the way the designer draw the form is using the setting for the IDE application (delphi32.exe or bds.exe's compatibility settings) so the answer is no. The default behaviour is different between IDE versions, for eg. the opposite behaviour (not drawing themed) happened in past.

Comment: Yes, but the OP is using Delphi 2010.

Comment: The D7 on XP is the example for an opposite situation where by default the IDE doesn't draw themed controls.

Comment: Also, Windows 6.0+ prefers manifest resource over manifest file

Comment: @Hasan The person asking the question is using D2010. It matters not one jot what D7 does.

Comment: Sorry didn't know this is a specific D2010 question. I've rephrased and removed the irrevant D7 case.

Comment: Yeah, pay more attention to the tags of the question - many times people put the version with tags like `delphi-2010`.